# Regular expression to match white space only when space found between only numeric values, and not find the space when comma found between two words

Tags: regex

Input:

```js
Price           45.0          50.0       43.5     43.0, 12.9 NOT FOUND
```

Expected output:

```
Price
45.0
50.0
43.5
43.0, 12.9
NOT FOUND
```

Regular Expression to match white space only when space found between only numeric values:

```java
"(?i)(?:(?<![a-z])\s+|\s+(?![a-z]))"
```

I don't want to detect space between 43.0, 12.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```java
(?<=[A-Za-z\d])\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Za-z])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uMHnjy/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=[A-Za-z\d])\s+(?=\d)` - one or more whitespace chars immediately preceded with an alphanumeric char and immediately followed with a digit
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Za-z])` - one or more whitespace chars immediately preceded with a digit char and immediately followed with a letter.

Comment: Can you please suggest me one more thing, If "NOT FOUND" "NOT FOUND" come twice continuously, then how to keep individual  "NOT FOUND" in separate lines.

Comment: @rominjariwala That is not clear because there is no technical way to differentiate between the `NOT` and `FOUND` and `FOUND` and `NOT`. So, it is not possible given the current requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative regex:

```
(?<=[a-z]|\d)\s+
```

Try it out at: https://regex101.com/